# Very low brightness after Windows Update graphics driver update

Tags: technical-issues, pc, windows, graphics-card, call-of-duty

When I try to play *Call of Duty*, the brightness becomes very low and I can't revert it. This started after a graphics driver update through Windows Update. I tried to increase the brightness from the game settings, but after a while (just seconds), it reverted back to black. I can see things, but all blackish. I have not had the same problem with other games.

I have an Intel Core 2 Duo, no external graphics card, and 4 GB RAM installed on my PC. I considered removing the update, but it's not possible now. There is no more "Graphics Driver Update," rather "4342493284234" in the Installed Updates section.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Windows Vista 64-bit. After some Googling, I found nothing but I did notice that people with Windows XP did not have the same problem. Anyways, here's my solution:

For Windows Vista/7 users, you'll need to run the game in Windows XP Service Pack 2 emulation mode.
Navigate to your Steam CoD installation: C:\\Steam\steamapps\common\call of duty
Right-click on CoDSP.exe and click Properties
In the Compatibility tab make sure the "Run this program in compatibility mode for:" is checked and change the drop-down to Windows XP (Service Pack 2)
Hit Apply and the OK

After this, I was able to change the brightness from in-game without a problem. If this still won't help, try running it as an Administrator. You can follow the above steps but the checkbox is further down in the Compatibility tab.

Answer (score 0):

Try heading to Control Panel, then to Device Manager. Find your video card under Display Adapters, right-click it and click Properties. Then click the Driver tab. Third button down should say "Roll Back Driver".

If it's clickable, you should be able to use it to take you back to a previous driver version.

If not, you may be able to find an older version of your graphics card driver online, then use the "Update Driver" button just above Roll Back to "update" your driver to the older version.

Answer (score 0):

Definitly uninstall the driver from windows update from Control Panel -> Device Manager. 
(right click and remove driver)

Navigate to the Intel website and find the driver straight from them.

If at all possible, always try to avoid these types of driver updates from Windows Update.

Good Luck!